# How create table behaves in transactions?

Tags: android, sqlite

I run two transactions.

In first transaction the table test is created,
but then I say rollback for this transaction.

I think that then the table test should have been created or not,
but not something between.

Then I run the other transaction to test what has happened:

I insert one row in the table test. 
That seems work in program but when I go to sqlite prompt,
I do not see the table test there when I say the command ".schema".

Can someone tell what is happening?

Output of my code is:
"Insert ok."

```
    try
    {
      db.beginTransaction();

      String s =
      "CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,age INTEGER)";
      db.execSQL(s);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Exception 1:"+e);
    }
    finally
    {
      db.endTransaction();
    }


    try
    {
      db.beginTransaction();
      db.execSQL("INSERT INTO test VALUES(NULL,22)");
      db.setTransactionSuccessful();
      System.out.println("Insert ok.");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Exception 2:"+e);
    }
    finally
    {
      db.endTransaction();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell what is happening?

It's normal behaviour. Your table wasn't created because you didn't commit `TRANSACTION` as well as your insert wasn't performed. Reason why you are getting result

```
System.out.println("Insert ok.");
```

is that execSQL() method throws SQLException only in the case if your **query string** is invalid / broken. And also you can't use execSQL() for inserting. You can use it only for altering tables.

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a
>   SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

### Solution:

Since `execSQL()` is void type you need to use `API` method [`insert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert) to test result.

```
long rowId = db.insert("test", <nullColumnHack>, values);
if (rowId < 0) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not ok. If I try to create the table test again in the second transaction (instead of using insert statement), that fails.

Comment: Yes, but still if I try to create the table test in second transaction, that fails and produces exception saying that table test exists. However no table in sqlite prompt after first transaction.

Comment: @heivik this is most likely caused because your db is still open and any changes, rollbacks will be applied  until you close db. So try to close db and again open before you are performing insertion test and let me know.

Comment: My insert is ok in android. The question was: If you roll back transaction, have you table you created in that transaction or not? In second transaction you can insert rows but after commit you can not see the table in sqlite prompt. Trying to create the table in second transaction produces exception. So what is happening?

Comment: i wrote you that your insert statement does not work! you can insert data via execSQL... this is reason but create table you can via execSQL and hence is thrown expcetion. did you tried what i said? close db and reopen again?..

Comment: My test was in onCreate() of class inherited from SQLiteOpenHelper. That bad because the whole method implicitly in transaction which we can be read from SQLiteOpenHelper methods getWritableDatabase() -> getDatabaseLocked() and there db.beginTransaction() before calling onCreate(). Nested ransactions caused this strange behaving. Sadly only source file SQLiteOpenHelper documents this feature of onCreate() method.

Comment: @heivik so i didnt know that your code was placed in onCreate() method. this explains everything :-